# Calculating distance discrepancy: EPSG 3112 Projection VS GeoDesic (Karney), is ~0.5% difference normal?

Tags: distance, epsg, accuracy, geodesic

I have lat-lng coords in EPSG:4326, and I'm calculating the distance between them (in metres).

Since these are in Australia (and Australia wide, therefore no specific MGA zone projections), I'm using the Australia wide (metres) projection **[EPSG-3112](https://epsg.io/3112)** (if there's a better EPSG projection for measuring distance Australia wide, please let me know).

I'm wondering if a discrepancy of ~0.5% / 0.4% (compared to Karney output) is normal?
From what I understand; Haversine is for spherical, Vincenty is for Ellipsoids, and Karney is a better Vincenty formula?

I am calculating the Karney distance using [GeoPy](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#module-geopy.distance).

Two examples of my measurements are:

- Mildura -> Bendigo:

  - EPSG:3112 - 342,215 m
  - Karney - 342,675 m
- Mildura -> Shepparton:

  - EPSG:3112 - 384,180 m
  - Karney - 384,358 m

But I also have similar discrepancies of 0.4% at smaller scales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no map projection which preserves distances.  So the errors
you're seeing are expected.  Measuring distances in a small area usually
won't help unless your area lies on one of the standard
parallels for the projection (lat = 18S or lat = 36S in the case of
epsg:3112).